# Endless Scrolling RecyclerView is not working when items in list are minimum then screen size

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have successfully implemented the Endless Scrolling using Recycler view. I am using [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) code and this works perfectly but except with the following case

**Case 1:**   When the list has 2 items which are lesser then the screen size so its looks like the OnLoadMore calls again as it finds itself arriving to the end of the list

**What I am doing:**  I am getting the list from 1 fragment and then send this list to the other fragment and in that fragment there is a RecyclerView with the onScroll listner here it is as follows :

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // do something...

                currentVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
                CallingMyApi();

        }
    });
```

**Confusions:**

- My RecyclerView add on scroll listener run first time when the fragments gets initialized. where as there is no scrolling performed.
- if there are lesser items let say 2 it runs always on fragment initiallized , in case of many items OnLoadMore methos does not runs.

So i can guess that it is problem due to the less items in the list view How to control that please help me ??

**Update 1:  My Fragment Code**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new EnrollmentSearchAdapter(getActivity(), parentList);

    rvSearchEnrollments.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // do something...

            if(parentList!=null && parentList.size()>3) { // just checking my own that 3 items should not be minimum to screen size , where as here it should be more flexible solution 
                currentVisiblePosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) rvSearchEnrollments.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
                SearchSundaySchoolParentsCouples searchSundaySchoolParentsCouples = new SearchSundaySchoolParentsCouples(keyword, 20, pageNumber, getActivity());
                searchSundaySchoolParentsCouples.execute();
            }
        }
    });

    rvSearchEnrollments.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));

    rvSearchEnrollments.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

Comment: If your CallingMyApi() is function in fragment then you can call it by taking your fragment reference into adapter class and use solution mentioned by Anand.

Comment: do y=to some reasons I have to use this in the fragment

Comment: Put your fragment code

Comment: i implemented a more efficient solution if you need it , in kotlin:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076179/835883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your load more task something like this in recyclerview if list are minimum then screen size

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.label.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
            holder.dateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmText2());

           if (position == this.getItemCount() - 1 &&  !loading){
                // do your load more task here
           }
  }
```

Comment: I am implementing this in fragment . Can I sort it out it there

Comment: please show me how can I do it in fragment , tell me the way

Comment: you are using recyclerview in fregment and you were setting adapter for the same recyclerview. In that adapter there will be a method onBindViewHolder. there you can do the the code as suggested.

Comment: I am using the library ]

Comment: This seems pretty hacky. @SharartiKAKA, check my answer for a trustworthy solution to your problem.

Comment: This one is the easiest way to do endless scrolling. Thank you. Works without '!loading'

Answer (score 8):

Use the [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622) `OnScrollListener` subclass (it's from a popular Gist). You'll need to change a few things in order to get an endless Scrolling RecyclerView working when the items in the list are minimum then screen size.

Here's what you need to add to the [EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/d09dc68ff07e845cc622) class:

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
{
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    // Don't do any work until after the ScrollEvent has ended, so do the following check.
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        // supply a positive number to recyclerView.canScrollVertically(int direction) to check if scrolling down.
        boolean canScrollDownMore = recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);
        // If recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) returns false it means you're at the end of the list.
        if (!canScrollDownMore)
        {
            //call the overridden onScrolled() method in our EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener class.
            // supply any positive number to the third argument to indicate that we've scrolled downward.
            onScrolled(recyclerView, 0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:** We need to implement the `onScrollStateChanged()` method because `onScrolled()` doesn't get called when at the end of a list, or at least it doesn't get called when the items in the list are minimum then screen size.

Here's the entire `EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener` class with the updates that you'll need:

```
public abstract class EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener
{
// The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
// before loading more.
private int visibleThreshold = 5;
// The current offset index of data you have loaded
private int currentPage = 0;
// The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;
// True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
private boolean loading = true;
// Sets the starting page index
private int startingPageIndex = 0;

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

public void setLayoutManager(RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager)
{
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
}

public RecyclerView.LayoutManager getLayoutManager()
{
    return layoutManager;
}

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager)
{
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
}

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager, int visibleThreshold)
{
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
}

public EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager,
        int visibleThreshold)
{
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
}

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions)
{
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
        else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize)
        {
            maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
        }
    }
    return maxSize;
}

// This happens many times a second during a scroll, so be wary of the code you place here.
// We are given a few useful parameters to help us work out if we need to load some more data,
// but first we check if we are waiting for the previous load to finish.
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy)
{
    if (dy < 1)
    {
        // don't do anything when scrolling up.
        return;
    }
    int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();

    if (layoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager)
    {
        int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) layoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
        // get maximum element within the list
        lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
    }
    else if (layoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager)
    {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) layoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }
    else if (layoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager)
    {
        lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    // If the total item count is zero and the previous isn't, assume the
    // list is invalidated and should be reset back to initial state
    if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount)
    {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        if (totalItemCount == 0)
        {
            this.loading = true;
        }
    }
    // If it’s still loading, we check to see if the dataset count has
    // changed, if so we conclude it has finished loading and update the current page
    // number and total item count.
    if (loading && (totalItemCount >= previousTotalItemCount))
    {
        loading = false;
        previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
    }

    // If it isn’t currently loading, we check to see if we have breached
    // the visibleThreshold and need to reload more data.
    // If we do need to reload some more data, we execute onLoadMore to fetch the data.
    // threshold should reflect how many total columns there are too
    if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount)
    {
        currentPage++;
        onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
        loading = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
{
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)
    {
        // supply a positive number to recyclerView.canScrollVertically(int direction) to check if scrolling down.
       boolean canScrollDownMore = recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1);
       // If recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1) returns false it means you're at the end of the list.
       if (!canScrollDownMore)
       {
           onScrolled(recyclerView, 0, 1);
       }
    }
}

// Call this method whenever performing new searches on in onRefresh() if using SwipeRefresh
public void resetState()
{
    this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
    this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
    this.loading = true;
}

// Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

}
```

**Brief sample of usage:** ([more info here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView))

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Store a member variable for the listener
    private EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Configure the RecyclerView
       RecyclerView rvItems = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvContacts);
       LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       rvItems.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
       // Retain an instance so that you can call `resetState()` for fresh searches
       scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
           @Override
           public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
               // Triggered only when new data needs to be appended to the list
               // Add whatever code is needed to append new items to the bottom of the list
               loadNextDataFromApi(page);
           }
      };
      // Adds the scroll listener to RecyclerView
      rvItems.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
  }

  // Append the next page of data into the adapter
  // This method probably sends out a network request and appends new data items to your adapter. 
  public void loadNextDataFromApi(int offset) {
      // Send an API request to retrieve appropriate paginated data 
      //  --> Send the request including an offset value (i.e `page`) as a query parameter.
      //  --> Deserialize and construct new model objects from the API response
      //  --> Append the new data objects to the existing set of items inside the array of items
      //  --> Notify the adapter of the new items made with `notifyItemRangeInserted()`
  }
}
```

You may need to modify things a bit to get it working in your scenario, but the code provided is a GREAT starting point.

Answer (score -1):

```
private boolean loading = true;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
{
    if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
    {
        visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) 
        {
            if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) 
            {
                loading = false;
                Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
            }
        }
    }
}
});

//Don't forgot to implement this
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: i have tried this too it does the same , the addOnScrollListener run when the fragment first start