# How to use infinite scrolling recyclerview inside nestedscrollview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, nestedscrollview

The height of the screen is not enough because there are many items containing two recyclerviews on one screen.
So I tried to have a child view in a nestedscrollview.
however, all the items are loaded at once, or recyclers are not recycled.

So I have read other articles and have tried but its not worked for me.

for example
To add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
or `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

If you know how to do it, please let me know. thanks for reading.

This is my java code

```
myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mcontext);
    mLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    mAdapter.setLinearLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter.setRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

and this is my xml code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/googleMap"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">



            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/tag_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager">

            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/map_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

this is my adapter code it is too many so i upload relevant part
It add a new item when reach the bottom of the recyclerview.

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}

public MyAdapter(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
    this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    mDataset = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setLinearLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
    this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
}

public void setRecyclerView(final RecyclerView mView) {
    mView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
                totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                lastVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!isMoreLoading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)<= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        isMoreLoading = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return mDataset.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new StudentViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.home_contents, parent, false));
    } else {
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new ProgressViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_progress, parent, false));
    }
}

public void addAll(List<mainitem> lst) {
    mDataset.clear();
    mDataset.addAll(lst);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addItemMore(List<mainitem> lst) {
    mDataset.addAll(lst);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(mDataset.size()-6, mDataset.size());
}


public void setMoreLoading(boolean isMoreLoading) {
    this.isMoreLoading=isMoreLoading;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataset.size();
}

public void setProgressMore(final boolean isProgress) {
    if (isProgress) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDataset.add(null);
                notifyItemInserted(mDataset.size() - 1);
            }
        });
    } else if(!isProgress) {
        mDataset.remove(mDataset.size() - 1);
        notifyItemRemoved(mDataset.size()-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`** to your **`RecyclerView`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/map_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"/>
```

Comment: I added it in my java code already, but it did not work for me

Comment: It changes my recyclerview like a linearlayout but thank you for your advise

Comment: @Jshin remove this ` app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` from recyclerview than try

Comment: It does not cause any events to occur when the first item is loaded but reached the bottom of the recycle view. 
Could you advise me on my adapter code?

Comment: @Jshin check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638845/7666442 for load more with recyclerviw using nested scrollview

Comment: It doesn't work perfectly, but now it reacts when it touches the bottom. I really appreciate your advice! really thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you

Comment: i implemented something i think can help a few people:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076179/835883

Answer (score 0):

The above solution **only works** if you are using api **version above 21**, if you want to support it with also **lower version** please **check** my answer
[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638779/pagination-not-work-for-the-recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview/52342036#52342036)